# Phpbb routing doesn't work

Tags: phpbb3

I am facing problem when routing in phpbb.
my routing.yml file looks like this:

```
test_hello_world_controller:
path: /id/{post_id}
defaults: { _controller: test.controller:doSomething }
requirements:
        post_id: \d+
```

but it gives error:

> No route found for "GET /id/43"

Comment: 1 - Could you provide us your config/services.yml file please ? 
2 - Could you provide us your phpbb version (3.1 or 3.2) ?

Comment: Thank you. but i solved the issue.. I had to delete the production folder from cache folder everytime i update my routing.yml file.

Comment: Could you publish that as an answer and accept it ? So, contributors won't loose time by reading your issue ? Thank you ! :)

Comment: Sorry For that :)

Comment: You should answer the question. then ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is this kind of problem :

1. You should have a look on your `config/services.yml` and check that dependance is well declared,
2. You should delete your cache folder everytime you update your `routing.yml` file.